# mod_rewrite help -- convert sub-directories to GET variables

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have an app sitting in http://mysite.com/myapp. I want to put an htaccess file in the /myapp folder such that all additional sub-directories get converted to a GET variable. E.g.

```
http://mysite.com/myapp => /myapp/index.php   # this is happening)
http://mysite.com/myapp/foo => index.php?sub=foo
http://mysite.com/myapp/bar/ => index.php?sub=bar/
http://mysite.com/myapp/foo/bar?baz=bop => index.php?sub=foo/bar&baz=bop
```

This ain't working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/.*)\?(.*) ./index.php?sub=$1&$2 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rule does not make sense as `RewriteRule` does not work with query string directly (means -- it's not part of the URL) -- it only works with path part of the URL (e.g. in `/foo/bar?baz=bop` path part will be `/foo/bar`). To **match** query string you have to use `RewriteCond`.

In your case you do not need to do even that ... as you are not "completely modifying/altering" existing query string .. just adding a bit to it.

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)(.*)$ index.php?sub=$1 [QSA,L]
```

1. `QSA` tells mod_rewrite to append current query string to the new one.

2. This rule excludes requests to `index.php` file to prevent infinite redirect loop.

**EDIT:**

3. This rule (as well as your own attempt) will rewrite requests to any URL including any existing files (e.g. images, css etc). To by-pass this "restriction" (I've wrote it using your example), add these lines just before RewriteRule line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: That's basically working, thanks! One thing isn't working: I have a link to a css file in the myapp directory (src="style.css") that doesn't load if I put a url like /myapp/foo/ (trailing slash) or /myapp/foo/bar (sub-sub), the css file doesn't load. It does with a single sub, though (/myapp/foo)

Comment: If this site is on your local PC or where you have full control over your Apache, then you can turn rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`  .. or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging for latest version) and look from there. Right now I cannot tell for sure what may be wrong and where.

Comment: On another hand -- try writing links to your css|js|images relative to the website root and not to the current file. For example: `/myapp/styles/main.css` instead of `../styles/main.css')

Comment: Yeah, obviously, I can do that, but I'd rather keep everything inside of /myapp portable if possible. I'll try the debugging thing.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it isn't. [Just like the docs say](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), you can't catch the query string in `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ ./index.php?sub=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Be careful with rewriting already rewritten URL -- your rule will match request to index.php as well.

Comment: That's what `RewriteCond !-f ...` is for.

Comment: Then add it -- otherwise your rule is incomplete -- when OP will copy-paste it it most likely will not work (based on other rules, of course).